# chrony keeps going in future

Tags: ntp, chrony

I have chrony installed on a centos 8 system and it keeps setting the time in the future by about 2 hours every 2 days. I have to keep restarting the service and do an `ntpdata` to fix itm and it is annoying. I have tried fiddeling with the config, but I am not quite sure what to do. Any ideas?

Here's my config:

```
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
pool 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Record the rate at which the system clock gains/losses time.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift

# Allow the system clock to be stepped in the first three updates
# if its offset is larger than 1 second.
makestep 1000 10

# Enable kernel synchronization of the real-time clock (RTC).
rtcsync

# Enable hardware timestamping on all interfaces that support it.
#hwtimestamp *

# Increase the minimum number of selectable sources required to adjust
# the system clock.
#minsources 2

# Allow NTP client access from local network.
#allow 192.168.0.0/16
allow 192.168.1.0/24
# Serve time even if not synchronized to a time source.
#local stratum 10

# Specify file containing keys for NTP authentication.
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys

# Get TAI-UTC offset and leap seconds from the system tz database.
leapsectz right/UTC

# Specify directory for log files.
logdir /var/log/chrony

# Select which information is logged.
#log measurements statistics tracking

[server ~]$ chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : A29FC87B (time.cloudflare.com)
Stratum         : 4
Ref time (UTC)  : Fri Mar 25 08:22:28 2022
System time     : 3662.770263672 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000199583 seconds
RMS offset      : 37.570960999 seconds
Frequency       : 14.564 ppm slow
Residual freq   : -0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.007 ppm
Root delay      : 0.038045153 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.000602906 seconds
Update interval : 1036.4 seconds
Leap status     : Normal

[server ~]$ date
Fri Mar 25 11:31:15 EET 2022
```

Comment: Could it be that your timezone is set two hours ahead (or behind)?

Comment: Well, the tz is indeed set to the local tz. Should it be set in UTC?

Comment: However, the clock offsets gradually, it can be by 30 minutes , 1 hour or moer off

Comment: Does chrony *ever* set the clock to the correct time? More details are required to be able to understand and help. At least NTP cannot fix broken clocks; that's for sure. Also show the output of `date -u`.

Answer (score 1):

Your clock is probably running faster than what can be corrected by the kernel. This may be a hardware or kernel issue, e.g. on a virtual machine.

Check the frequency value printed by `chronyc tracking`. If it's larger than 100000 ppm, you will need to permanently enable clock steps by changing the `makestep` directive to:

```
makestep 1 -1
```

But this should be used only as the last resort if you cannot fix the clock.